# Sentinel Analytics Rule with two tables

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create a detection rule, that would receive alerts from MCAS and extract the user from that event and perform a SigninLogs query to check if that user used a specific user-agent. I've tried using union to merge both tables, but my where clause it's not working.

```
SecurityAlert
| where ProviderName contains "MCAS"
| union SigninLogs
| extend user = CompromisedEntity
| where user == UserPrincipalName
| project user, AlertName, UserPrincipalName
```

And got nothing. Basically I'm expecting to find if a user used a specific user-agent on SigninLogs

Is there anyway to perform a query within a query and create a rule based on that?

Comment: Please provide sample data for both tables (as datatable / CSV) + required results (CSV)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've solved this by now, but I want to try answer it for anyone who searches for the same issues.

A union isn't what is needed here, it will just join the two tables like layering a cake with one table on top of another. Columns that have the same name and data type sharing the same columns and those which are different standing alone.

Joins are needed to compare like for like data, and using LET statements makes it easier to break the query into its smaller components.

It is worth noting that this query below makes the assumption that you only want to process alerts that have account entities, we can build a user principal name with and have had successful sign ins. You can make the modifications to match your needs.

kind regards

Alistair

```
// Get the alerts first that have account entities
let MCASAlert = 
    SecurityAlert
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) // Your alert frequency
    | where ProviderName == "MCAS"
    | where Entities has "\"Type\":\"account\""
;
// Now modify them to extract the entities per alert
let MCASAlertAccounts = 
    MCASAlert
    | mv-expand todynamic(Entities)
    | where Entities.Type =~ "account"
    | extend UserPrincipalName = tolower(strcat(tostring(Entities.Name), "@", tostring(Entities.UPNSuffix)))
    | project SystemAlertId, UserPrincipalName, StartTime
;
// Now we need to process the SignInLogs and find the likely Sign in events releated to the alert.
let UserAgentResults = SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(14d)
| extend UserPrincipalName = tolower(UserPrincipalName)
| where ResultType == "0" // include this if you only want successful sign ins
| project TimeGenerated, UserPrincipalName, UserAgent
| join kind=inner (
    MCASAlertAccounts
    )
    on UserPrincipalName
| where TimeGenerated between ((StartTime - 5m) .. StartTime) // include a time range for the sign in events. These aren't going to line up perfectly with the MCAS alert, so allow tolerance
| extend UserAgents = pack("TimeGenerated", TimeGenerated, "UserAgent", UserAgent) // Pack them for formatting. You don't need to include TimeGenerated, though you may want other details as well
| summarize UserAgents = make_set(UserAgents) by SystemAlertId, UserPrincipalName;
MCASAlert
| join kind=inner ( // Join them to the original Alerts
    UserAgentResults
) on SystemAlertId
```